# PHPStorm not recognising more than 2 chained public methods

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

This doesn't affect the code, but it is kind of annoying.

I have these 3 methods inside my controller:

```
public function chainOne()
{
    return $this;
}

public function chainTwo()
{
    return $this;
}

public function chainThree()
{
    return $this;
}
```

The method that is being called once hitting the specific route is this:

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $this->chainOne()
            ->chainTwo()
            ->chainThree();

}
```

PHPStorm says `method chainThree() not found in class $this`. But the code inside `chainThree()` is being executed without a problem.

How can I fix it? Is it a bug?

Comment: This should a bug in PhpStorm (at least I see it this way). This one sounds related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use docblocks to help PHPStorm recognize the return value:

```
public class Foo
{

    /**
    * @return Foo $this
    */
    public function chainOne()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return Foo $this
    */
    public function chainTwo()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return Foo $this
    */
    public function chainThree()
    {
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: @SuchMuchCode And what will happen if you use this in child class? Instead of resolving `$this` into current class it will stay at parent `Foo`...

Comment: You don't even need to add `Foo`, just `@return $this` is sufficient and keeps your code "rename-proof".